# Can I use resource transparent images commercially as a resource to my SAAS, which I scraped from a website?

Tags: images, legal, copyright, resources, scraper-sites

I want to develop a product image editing SAAS, which will let the users select a product and edit the image and download with following steps:

1. Select the product
2. Load the transparent mockup image of the product with an image overlay
3. Add effects using SAAS tools or add text (SAAS will keep adding layers for all these effects)
4. Download the final image

In above steps, I would need the mockup transparent images of different products, so there are two ways to get those:

1. I can download original product images from any e-commerce website
   and create mockup in photoshop for each product, also I need to
   remove their branding info from image.
2. As there are plenty of websites providing same SAAS, so I
   scrape those to download their resource files to get those product
   transparent images, ready to use.

So if I go with the 2nd option, will there be any copyright consequences?, as the website, from where I have scraped resource images, had put their efforts and money to build all those mockup image files. I thought of using those because those are publicly available without any watermark or credentials.

Note: Neither the transparent resource files are visible directly on websites, from where I have scrapped them nor those will be visible directly on my SAAS, they are always layered with one more overlay images.

Comment: This is a question for a legal expert.  Given it might mean you lose everything you own in a law suit, I am not sure I would trust the opinion of someone from a website I have just joined.

Comment: I have not created any such SAAS yet, but I am willing to, and however as per my knowledge, a properly altered image, which doesn't look like a copy of original image can be used, but in my scenario, I am not modifying the copied image, but the final outcome visible on UI is different due to multi layer overlay on the top of copied image.
So if someone wants to check whether I am using their resource image, they would need to go to browser's dev tools and keep an eye on all the img resources downloaded and compare with their image.

Comment: Fair enough.  Your question is about copyright.  You need legal advice, not an opinion

Comment: May be somebody from here, has already been into same situation and can answer my query as per his/her experience. Post this if needed I would be considering a legal expert for further advice, at least I would have an idea at that point of time, after discussing out this here.